# Access to old macbook files on new mac?

Tags: backup

I've got a 2015-ish Macbook with a dying battery. I have setup a new Macbook from scratch, installing the apps I wanted, etc.

What I would like to do is make a backup of the old Macbook before it dies completely, and either keep that all in a single directory on the new box, or mount an image of the old one occasionally.

What's I'm trying to do is give myself an emergency plan for: "oh! I had that random config file on the old laptop, let me grab that!" I am not expecting to run apps that were installed on the old one, but just being able to look at the Applications directory would be useful as a reminder, as would the contents of /usr/local (for Homebrew), and the dotfiles in ~, etc. What I don't trust is my ability to remember everything I'll ever want right now. So I want to grab it all and be able to go diffing when I need it.

I'm looking for recommendations on how to do this, and tradeoffs for various methods. I really would like the whole volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most frequently recommended tools for creating images on macs are:

SuperDuper: https://shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper
CarbonCopyCloner: https://bombich.com/

Both will image the mac and convert it to a single image file you can store.

You could also just connect the two machines and put the old one in Target Disk Mode: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-mac-computers-target-disk-mode-mchlp1443/mac

Then you can copy the files off, or generate an image. Disk Utility can generate an image from a folder, so you could select the drive on the old mac and image it.

Comment: I'm aware of both of those. But never used. On the new machine, can I then mount the img file SuperDuper (or CCC) created?

Comment: Yes - they'll generate either a disk image file (there are some option exactly what sort), that'll mount up as a fake disk on your new machine, similar to how many Mac apps are shipped. You'll obviously need as much disk space on the new machine to store that image as you had on your old machine.